# Same thing freezes or works in an instant

Tags: haskell

The code below solves this [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/functional-programming-the-sums-of-powers):

> Find the number of ways in which a given integer, X, can be expressed as the sum of the the Nth power of unique natural numbers.

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Map ((!),fromList,Map(..),member)

-- depth first search higher order function
depthFirstSearch :: (node -> [node]) -> -- successor node generator
                   (node -> Bool) -> -- is goal checker
                   [node] -> -- starting root nodes
                   [node] -- goal nodes
depthFirstSearch succ goal roots = search' roots
  where search' [] = []
        search' (x:xs) | goal x = x : search' xs
                       | otherwise = search' (succ x ++ xs)


type Degree = Int
type CurrentSum = Int
type CurrentNumber = Int
type Node = (CurrentNumber,CurrentSum)
type Goal = Int

-- generates valid successor nodes
succN :: Goal -> Map Int Int -> Node -> [Node]
succN goal _map (i,sum) = do
  i' <- [(i+1)..goal]
  guard (member i' _map)
  let sum' = sum + _map!i'
  guard (sum' <= goal)
  return (i',sum')
-- checks if the node is the goal
goalN :: Goal -> Node -> Bool
goalN goal (_,sum) = goal == sum

-- counts solutions
solCount :: Degree -> Goal -> Int
solCount d goal =
  let roots = [(i,i^d) | i <- [1..goal], i^d <= goal]
      _map = Map.fromList roots
      nodes = depthFirstSearch (succN goal _map) (goalN goal) roots
      c = length nodes
  in c
```

Strange thing is happening. It freezes on `solCount 10 1000`. If I run the `solCount` manually in `ghci` it freezes as expected

```
let roots = [(i,i^10) | i <- [1..1000], i^10 <= 1000] -- [(1,1)]
let _map = Map.fromList roots 
let nodes = depthFirstSearch (succN 1000 _map) (goalN 1000) roots
nodes
```

But when it is replaced with the "same" thing like this

```
let nodes = depthFirstSearch (succN 1000 $ Map.fromList [(1,1)]) (goalN 1000) [(1,1)]
nodes
```

it prints the result instantly. I have no idea why it's freezing and not freezing.

Comment: I would suggest breaking that `depthFirstSearch` function up into a few. Not because it's wrong (I believe it is right), but because it's confusing. I would probably use `unfoldTree` from `Data.Tree` to build a tree, prune the tree at the goal nodes, and then extract all the leaves. Unfortunately, `Data.Tree` is missing a lot of the functions that would make this really easy; they may be added in the next version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption:

```
let roots = [(i,i^10) | i <- [1..1000], i^10 <= 1000] -- [(1,1)]
```

for Ints is not true due to overflow. You can fix this by performing the comparisons using Integers and converting:

```
let roots = [(b,b^10) | a <- [(1::Integer)..1000], a^1000 <= 1000, let b = fromInteger a ]
```

You probably didn't spot this problem because ghci defaults to Integers in the REPL, but in your code `roots` has type `[Int]`.